# Issues connecting via SSH to GCE instance in us-central1

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is anyone else having issues connecting via SSH to their GCE instances in us-central1? I'm not able to connect since last night Feb 23 2021 ~5pm PST.

I'm using Google managed keys and using their GCE console-based SSH utility (click the SSH button from my instance in GCE). I've also tried connecting via SSH in Cloud Shell, and that is also timing out.

It tries and tries and always ends up timing out with "cannot connect due to an error. try again later (#15)".

Last night around the same time https://status.cloud.google.com had a yellow banner at the top stating "GCE instance connectivity issues due to Live Migrations". So I figured it was widespread.

Tried again this morning, GCP status page no longer had the banner, and SSH connection attempts still time out. Ironically the GCP status page now says "February 24, 2021 Multiple services reporting issues" - so I'm thinking I can't be the only one unable to connect to my instances.

This is especially critical for me right now as I was about to take something live to production, but I need to make a change to the server before then. It could not be worse timing - I've even had to postpone a marketing campaign.

Please if anyone can confirm it's not just me I'd really appreciate it.

Note I've also called Google support but don't have a paid plan, so they were limited in their ability to help me. Would appreciate any feedback/input from the community.

Comment: I confirm I can connect to my instance at us-central1-a. I suggest you launching a new VM instance in the same zone as your server and try connecting from it

Comment: Thank you @surfingonthenet for that. I am considering doing so, but this particular instance has over a months worth of work on it, and I was about to take it live. I'd have to rebuild everything in a new instance - which, if doing things right, would be templated and automated - but I hadn't gotten there yet. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

GCP always encourages their customers to distribute their resources across several zones in order to have availability.

You can create a snapshot of your instance and deploy it in a new zone:

You will need to create a Snapshot to backup your data in your VM instance and use the snapshot to create new instance so that you can still access your data in your newly created instance.

To create snapshot, please follow the steps below:

```
1. Go to Compute Engine page
2. Look for the snapshot then click it.
3. Click "Create Snapshot" button.
4. Look for the source disk this is the disk of your VM instance that you want to create snapshot.
5. Check the other settings like name etc and once you are done, please click "Create" button.
```

To create new instance using the new created snapshot, please follow the steps below:

```
1. Go to Compute Engine page > then select Snapshot.
2. Click the name of the Snapshot you created.
3. Select "CREATE INSTANCE" button.
4. Please check all your settings and don't forget to choose your instance neew zone.
5. Once you're done, please click "Create" button.
```

Also you could try changing the instance form zone, let me provide you with the instructions for you to do so:

1.Go to Google Cloud Platform >>> Compute Engine

2.Go to Snapshots >>> create a snapshot >>> Select your Compute Engine instance

3.Once snapshot is completed click on snapshot.

4.Under "snapshot details". There, on the top, just click create instance. Here you are basically creating an instance with a copy of your disk.

5.Select your new zone setup previous setting, create new name.

6.Click create, at this point your image should now be running in the new zone